# Size() method of list is not providing the correct result

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to get the number of result links in the yatra.com site. text from the list is displaying appropriate result but the size() method of list is not showing the correct result.

```
public class Yatra {

    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",`enter code here` "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.yatra.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_origin_city")).sendKeys("BLR");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_origin_city")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_arrival_city")).sendKeys("DEL");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_arrival_city")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        driver.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_depart_date")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("a_2017_10_25")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_flsearch_btn")).submit();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        List<WebElement> myResult = driver.findElements(By.id("resultList_0"));
        for (int j = 0; j < myResult.size(); j++) {
            WebElement display = myResult.get(j);
            String text = display.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        System.out.println(myResult.size());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
[Output file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe8dkcx83fuki5w/output.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you try printing out all the elements in the list and debug?

Comment: Yes i did printed out the elements.kindly view the output file uploaded

Comment: Am getting This site can’t provide a secure connection

Comment: @santhoshkumar : updated the ouput link. Please check

Comment: what does myResult.size() gives?

Comment: @santhoshkumar: myResult.size() is giving 2

Comment: @Rohit What size do you expect? I've just checked and there are really two elemets with that mentioned id.

Comment: @AlexeyR.I was hoping to get the complete count of the flights listed in the result List.

Comment: @Rohit then you need to set less specific locator in your code. For example //div[contains(@class, 'js-flightRow')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that the element locator that has been used to capture the result needs to be changed.

Try with the below xpath and hope this help you.

```
List<WebElement> myResult = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='results spr-push']//div/ul"));
```

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is working as expected. hope you are using independent dependent method of xpath.

Comment: Sorry Santhosh not enough reputation to accept the answer. However i am getting the result as expected. Thank you. sorry its not independent dependent method. its used for identifying dynamic elements through parent/sibling traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Change your locator to some less specific one. E.g. change:

`driver.findElements(By.id("resultList_0"));`

to

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'js-flightRow')]"));`

Comment: @Rohit, you should then consider this to accept as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Is correct. There are 2 WebElements inside `List<WebElement> myResult`.
Try:

```
        List<WebElement> myResult = driver.findElements(By.id("resultList_0"));
        System.out.println("BEFORE: " + myResult.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < myResult.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println("VALUE J: "  + j );
            WebElement display = myResult.get(j);
            String text = display.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
        }
        System.out.println("AFTER: " + myResult.size());
```

The output is:

```
BEFORE: 2
VALUE J: 0
AIRLINE  
DEPART  
ARRIVE  
DURATION  
PRICE PER ADULT
------------------------------
VALUE J: 1
Jet Airways

9W - 818
05:40
08:15
02h 35m
Non Stop
Rs.3,367
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 836
07:00
09:40
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.3,367
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 808
15:15
17:55
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.3,367
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Spicejet

SG - 192
09:30
12:20
02h 50m
Non Stop
Rs.3,636
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air

G8 - 116
08:10
10:50
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.3,650
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 3988
17:00
19:45
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.3,650
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 4065
12:20
15:15
02h 55m
Non Stop
Rs.3,650
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air

G8 - 120
11:25
14:20
02h 55m
Non Stop
Rs.3,650
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 812
19:45
22:30
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.3,892
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air

G8 - 118
20:45
23:30
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.4,100
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Spicejet

SG - 136
05:55
08:30
02h 35m
Non Stop
Rs.4,214
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Spicejet

SG - 150
00:20
03:05
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.4,214
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Spicejet

SG - 198
21:10
00:05
27 Oct
02h 55m
Non Stop
Rs.4,214
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 305
21:00
00:05
27 Oct
03h 05m
Non Stop
Rs.4,237
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 840
16:10
21:05
04h 55m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.4,634
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 822
16:10
09:15
27 Oct
17h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.4,634
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 740
16:10
16:10
27 Oct
24h 00m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.4,634
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 7064
16:10
20:00
27 Oct
27h 50m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.4,634
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air Asia

I5 - 722
23:50
02:35
27 Oct
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.4,809
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 828
16:10
04:55
27 Oct
12h 45m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.4,844
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7146 / 339
22:45
05:10
27 Oct
06h 25m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.4,994
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 449 / 339
21:55
05:10
27 Oct
07h 15m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.4,994
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 416 / 339
16:15
05:10
27 Oct
12h 55m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.4,994
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 831
16:10
22:15
06h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.5,159
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2314 / 736
16:10
13:20
27 Oct
21h 10m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.5,159
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7051 / 7071
21:05
01:10
27 Oct
04h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Pune
Rs.5,172
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2847 / 372
13:35
22:15
08h 40m
1 Stop(s)
via Pune
Rs.5,172
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2847 / 7071
13:35
01:10
27 Oct
11h 35m
1 Stop(s)
via Pune
Rs.5,172
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 246
13:00
15:40
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.5,220
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 475
04:30
07:15
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,220
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 367
08:35
11:20
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,220
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 978
14:40
17:25
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,220
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 289
21:55
00:55
27 Oct
03h 00m
Non Stop
Rs.5,220
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 943
09:55
13:00
03h 05m
Non Stop
Rs.5,220
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 501
13:30
16:10
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.5,315
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 804
06:10
08:55
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,315
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 505
10:00
12:45
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,315
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 173
21:10
23:55
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,315
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 478 / 331
07:00
12:10
05h 10m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7001 / 307
08:00
13:40
05h 40m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 410 / 331
05:45
12:10
06h 25m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 478 / 307
07:00
13:40
06h 40m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7001 / 351
08:00
15:15
07h 15m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 410 / 307
05:45
13:40
07h 55m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 478 / 351
07:00
15:15
08h 15m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7001 / 305
08:00
17:10
09h 10m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 410 / 351
05:45
15:15
09h 30m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 478 / 305
07:00
17:10
10h 10m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7146 / 301
22:45
09:05
27 Oct
10h 20m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7146 / 346
22:45
09:35
27 Oct
10h 50m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 449 / 301
21:55
09:05
27 Oct
11h 10m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 410 / 305
05:45
17:10
11h 25m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,362
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 416 / 309
16:15
21:15
05h 00m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,467
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7133 / 353
12:50
19:05
06h 15m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,467
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 416 / 361
16:15
23:10
06h 55m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,467
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7133 / 311
12:50
20:10
07h 20m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,467
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7133 / 309
12:50
21:15
08h 25m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,467
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7133 / 361
12:50
23:10
10h 20m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.5,467
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
NON REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 484
23:00
01:45
27 Oct
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.5,500
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Vistara

UK - 868
06:50
09:25
02h 35m
Non Stop
Rs.5,646
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Vistara

UK - 812
09:55
12:35
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.5,646
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Vistara

UK - 816
12:15
15:05
02h 50m
Non Stop
Rs.5,646
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 855 / 564
18:45
23:40
04h 55m
1 Stop(s)
via Hyderabad
Rs.5,880
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 564 / 43
11:50
23:55
12h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.6,071
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 564 / 440
11:50
08:55
27 Oct
21h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.6,071
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 564 / 143
11:50
11:35
27 Oct
23h 45m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.6,071
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 564 / 430
11:50
12:55
27 Oct
25h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.6,071
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 132
06:05
08:45
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.6,072
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2736 / 822
22:25
09:15
27 Oct
10h 50m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.6,307
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 2312 / 822
20:35
09:15
27 Oct
12h 40m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.6,307
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 503
17:00
19:45
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.6,365
Book Now
2 Seat(s) Left!
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 665 / 7143
02:50
08:35
05h 45m
1 Stop(s)
via Kolkata
Rs.6,758
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 602 / 846
05:30
10:00
04h 30m
1 Stop(s)
via Hyderabad
Rs.7,361
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 729 / 704
20:50
01:40
27 Oct
04h 50m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.7,471
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 583 / 466
07:10
10:45
27 Oct
27h 35m
2 Stop(s)
via Trivandrum, Kochi
Rs.7,547
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Vistara

UK - 836
20:50
23:30
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.7,641
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 808
18:55
21:45
02h 50m
Non Stop
Rs.7,995
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 7120
21:35
00:15
27 Oct
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.8,286
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 973
09:20
12:05
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.8,286
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 820
11:25
14:10
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.8,286
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 783
18:00
20:45
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.8,657
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 816
17:45
20:30
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.8,811
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 186 / 966
07:30
12:05
04h 35m
1 Stop(s)
via Hyderabad
Rs.9,045
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 564 / 539
11:50
19:50
08h 00m
1 Stop(s)
via Chennai
Rs.9,116
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 604 / 677
08:50
15:10
06h 20m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.9,536
Book Now
2 Seat(s) Left!
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Vistara

UK - 818
19:30
22:30
03h 00m
Non Stop
Rs.9,783
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Jet Airways

9W - 959 / 728
06:10
13:30
07h 20m
1 Stop(s)
via Patna
Rs.9,830
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 6228
07:05
09:45
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.10,305
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 6726
20:00
23:05
03h 05m
Non Stop
Rs.10,305
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Indigo

6E - 369 / 162
14:25
19:20
04h 55m
1 Stop(s)
via Ahmedabad
Rs.10,411
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 640 / 809
06:45
12:15
05h 30m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.10,586
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 776 / 21
06:05
12:10
06h 05m
1 Stop(s)
via Kolkata
Rs.13,053
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Air India

AI - 608 / 101
17:40
23:10
05h 30m
1 Stop(s)
via Mumbai
Rs.15,048
Book Now
4 Seat(s) Left!
FLIGHT DETAILS
FREE MEALS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air

G8 - 285
15:35
20:15
04h 40m
1 Stop(s)
via Goa
Rs.19,433
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air Business

88 - 116
08:10
Business
10:50
02h 40m
Non Stop
Rs.19,535
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air Business

88 - 118
20:45
Business
23:30
02h 45m
Non Stop
Rs.19,535
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
Go Air Business

88 - 120
11:25
Business
14:20
02h 55m
Non Stop
Rs.19,535
Book Now
FLIGHT DETAILS
REFUNDABLE
eCash Rs. 500
------------------------------
AFTER: 2
```